# How do I access in Python the link text of a symlink?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems, symlink

For a file-system comparison tool in Python I want to find out what the link text of a symbol link is. I do not want to follow the link, bur rather find the link text and whether it is absolute or relative.

Example: For a link which via `ls -l` prints

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tutor  staff    16B 25 Aug 17:13 etc -> dir-with-dir/etc
```

I would like to retrieve the text "dir-with-dir/etc" exactly in this relative form.

How can I access this information in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`os.readlink(path)`** to find the linked file of a symbolic link. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.readlink):

> Return a string representing the path to which the symbolic link points.

Also check out this more detailed answer in a related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426912/3628578

Comment: Getting the *resolved* path is exactly what I want to avoid. But the answer to the duplicate question gives me the right clue to use `os.readlink()`.

Comment: Cool - I updated my answer just for completeness sake in case someone else gets to this thread.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - step by step making StackOverflow a better place. :-) (BTW, I just corrected the location of the `readlink` function and its doco link: `readlink` resides in the `os` module not in `os.path`.